# Restricting access on root directory

Tags: linux

I just created a non-root user on my Kali Linux, however why I can still access the root directory? How do I restrict the user from accessing it?

Also I can't create files from there but still able to access the directory

Comment: Which directory? `/` or `/root`?

Comment: /root directory

Answer (score 0):

For directories, you have three permissions:

1. Read
2. Write
3. Execute

***Read*** allows you to list the content of a directory, with for instance `ls`.

***Execute*** allows you to enter the directory, and read contents of files, if you either have a read permission, or know the filename. If you have read, but not execute on `/root` you can only read a file if you know the filename.

***Write*** allows you to create, delete or modify any subdirectories, even if the file or subdirectory is owned by some other user.

To restrict the Write to only apply to users own files, the sticky bit can be set for the directory. This is done with `/tmp` for instance

To restrict `/root` to root only, simply run `chmod 700 /root`.

Note that doing this to other system directories may wreak havoc on your installation.